# Syntax error 1073

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors

I'm getting this compiling error but am not quite sure how to fix it -

### *1073: Syntax error: expecting a catch or a finally clause.*

```
   function __setProp___id98__Dage_APOP_Content_0()
    {
        if (__setPropDict[__id98_] == undefined || !(int(__setPropDict[__id98_]) >= 1                  && int(__setPropDict[__id98_]) <= 5))
        {
            __setPropDict[__id98_] = currentFrame;
            try
            {
                __id98_["componentInspectorSetting"] = true;
            }
            catch (e:Error)
            {
                try
                {
                }
                __id98_["componentInspectorSetting"] = false;
            }
            catch (e:Error)
            {
            }
        }
        return;
    } // end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your catch block has been misplaced. This code is also very redundant, possibly generated from a decompiler?

```
function __setProp___id98__Dage_APOP_Content_0() {
    if (__setPropDict[__id98_] == undefined|| !(int(__setPropDict[__id98_]) >= 1 && int(__setPropDict[__id98_]) <= 5)) {
        __setPropDict[__id98_] = currentFrame;
        try {
            __id98_["componentInspectorSetting"] = true;
        } catch (e:Error) {
            try {
                __id98_["componentInspectorSetting"] = false;
            } catch(e:Error) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it didn't work the second time I previewed it. "1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace."

Comment: @JeffreyByfuglien After looking through the code in the answer, it would appear that the error isn't in that code. I see no missing parens anywhere. It must be elsewhere in the code.